# update column data mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I have the table name course which has coursename column.

As you can see "seaadventures" and "sea adventures" etc.. info names are different, and want to make it to "sea adventures" for all matched words "seaadventures", How can I check and update it across DB ?

**coursename:**

```
seaadventures watersport1
sea adventures watersport2
cool seaadventures sport
```

Comment: You havn't checked the manual have you? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `REPLACE()` function,

```
UPDATE  tableName
SET     courseName  = REPLACE(courseName, 'seaadventures', 'sea adventures')
```

Answer (score 1):

Just [REPLACE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) every `seaadventures` to `sea adventures`

```
UPDATE course 
SET coursename = REPLACE(coursename, 'seaadventures', 'sea adventures')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
Update course Set coursename='sea adventures' where coursename like '%seaadventures%'
```